# MySQL Query to get all Children in tree when we pass parent_id

Tags: mysql, recursive-query, hierarchical-query

I have been looking at the query resulting total number of employees under an superior emp_id that has been passed to the query.

Example : for emp_id 1 he has '2,3,4,5' as reportees and under again for 
emp_id 3 there are '6,7' are reportess and again under 
emp_id 6 there are '8,9' are reportees and again under 
emp_id 9 there is a reportee '10'

Now when I pass the manger_id '1' to the Query I should get all 9 employees.

Below is my query, that is not working if there are 40 employees under an single employee.

```
    SELECT manager_id,emp_id FROM users ,(SELECT @head := 2) head
    WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(manager_id, @head) > 0 AND @head := CONCAT(@head, "," , emp_id) ORDER BY manager_id
```

In my table structure there is a manager_id column for each emp_id

Please help either with the MySQL query of MySQL function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean recursive query?

If yes, You can read this document: Trees in SQL: [Nested Sets and Materialized Path](http://www.dbazine.com/oracle/or-articles/tropashko4/)

This way not use query to get tree data, are use table structure to get same data. It is easy to query.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below query. You can either put manager id value hard coded in "initialization" part or you can pass variable.

```
select  EmpID,
        ManagerID 
from    (select ManagerID, EmpID from employee
         order by ManagerID, EmpID) employee_sorted,
        (select @pv := '1') initialization
where   find_in_set(ManagerID, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', EmpID)
```

Comment: This is the query which I have posted in the in Question, But this is not working for some scenarios where reportees exceeds more that 35.